# SCSI sense to string

Tags: c, string, character-arrays

As most of the guys will know who have worked with SCSI, if a SCSI command is issued, the device can return a so called sense code with additional information.

Basically you have 3 numbers which together have a meaning.

Here is a list on wikipedia:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_Code_Qualifier

I need have a function which takes these 3 numbers and identifies what error has occured and return a char array based on it.
I keep thinking of a good way to do it. branching if statements seem so unelegant...

I wonder if there is an easy way to do this without some complicated functions.

Answer (score 1):

A nested switch is the worst thing you can do for this kind of problem. A lookup table is much simpler. You probably need something like this:

```
struct SCSILookupTableElement
{
  unsigned char key;
  unsigned char asc;
  unsigned char ascq;
  const char *errorcondition;
} SCSILookupTable[] =
{
  {   0,    0,    0,      "No error"},
  {   0, 0x5d,    0,      "No sense - PFA threshold reached"},
  {   1,    1,    0,      "Recovered Write error - no index"},
  ...
  {0xff,    5,    0,      "Illegal request"}  // 0xff stands for X
  ...
};


const char *SCSIErrortext(int key, int asc, int ascq)
{
  int i ;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(SCSILookupTable)/sizeof(struct SCSILookupTableElement); i++)
  {
    if (  (SCSILookupTable[i].key == key || SCSILookupTable[i].key == 0xff)
        && SCSILookupTable[i].asc == asc
        && SCSILookupTable[i].ascq == ascq)
    {
      return SCSILookupTable[i].errorcondition;
    }
  }

  return "Unknown error";
}


void main()
{
  printf ("%s\n", SCSIErrortext(0, 0x5d, 0));
  printf ("%s\n", SCSIErrortext(0xfe, 0x05, 0));
  printf ("%s\n", SCSIErrortext(0x00, 0x05, 0));
}
```

It can hardly be simpler, though there is certainly room for improvement.

Comment: The unidentified complication to this is that the sense key is independent of the ASC/ASCQ numbers so you'd need to have many multiples of pretty similar strings instead of resolving each parts of the codes separately and then combine it with sprintf.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at libscsicmd which is a library I'm slowly working on. It includes both a  sense buffer parser and mapping of the KCQ to strings for human consumption.

It can be found at http://github.com/baruch/libscsicmd

To answer your direct question though, the Sense Key and the ASC/ASCQ are independent so I chose to return two different strings, one for the sense key and another for the ASC/ASCQ pair each of these is resolved with a largish switch statement that is auto-generated from the T10 text file.

If you then want a single string simply combine it with sprintf or strcat.

Comment: thanks I will take a look :). actually yesterday after some more reading I did exactly what you have done and wrote a little python script which converts the t10 plain text document to a lookup table. also with sense and ASQ/ASCQ seperated. I also added a status lookup.